# android, auth, keep HTTP connection, use connection in few Activity

Tags: android, http, authentication

in my app i try to get access to some web service. I'm going through form based authentication and getting an authorized connection. If i passed authorization i want open new Activity, but any new instance of DefaultHttpClient got unauthorized right.

And questions is: 
1) How pass this connection through activity 
2) Or how keep connection authorized correctly, if i think about httpclient interceptor, I'm on the right way? If, yes, then first question remain, but relativity of pass CookieStore data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost **always** make a class that handles your Http Requests call is **ConnectionManager** thats the most common name. 
And you should make it with Singleton Design Pattern. This way your connections will be handled correctly.

```
public class ConnectionManager {
    private static ConnectionManager instance = null;
private DefaultHttpClient client;

    private ConnectionManager() {
        client = new DefaultHttpClient(...);
    }
    //public method that will be invoked from other classes.
    public static ConnectionManager getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
        instance = new ConnectionManager();
        }
       return instance;
    }

    public void authenticate(){
 // Do your auth call with the client here
}

    public void postStuff(){
 // Use the same client here, this way you keep using the same client for ALL of your calls.
}
}
```

When you need to use the ConnectionManager use this:

```
private static ConnectionManager conn = ConnectionManager.getInstance();
conn.authenticate();
conn.postStuff();
```

Comment: thanks for fast reply, now i have class that extends of DefaultHttpClient. I try realize method like this [link](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/singleton/) but I did not succeed, you're talking about this? The meaning of the code should return a copy of the instanceю

Comment: Thanks for solution! I removed from my class extend of DefaultHttpClient, all done, worked nicely. Only one I've corrected a small mistake in your reply. And this is not exactly important, but purely hypothetical, I can use multithreading later by this method? Like doing two postStuff() at once? Or client.execute(url)?

Comment: If you want to use multithreading you should use ThreadSafeConnectionManager or AndroidHttpClient instead of DefaultHttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

[Subclass the Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html).  You'll need to list it in the manifest so that it is created.  You'll be able to retrieve it from within any activity.

```
public class ClientApplication extends Application {
    Session Session = null;

    public Session getSession() {
        return Session;
    }

    public void setSession(Session session) {
        Session = session;
    }
}
```

elsewhere

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Start");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.startresume);

    ClientApplication app = ((ClientApplication)getApplication());
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, looks like it should be, but I stopped at the second solution.