# Creating a singleton for maintaining TCP socket connection across different activities in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, singleton

As the title suggests, I am trying to create a singleton class for maintaining a TCP socket across different activities in my application. 
I am almost an absolute beginer to this and would really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

UPDATE:

Here is the code for the class that I wrote:

```
public static ConnectionManager getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
    instance = new ConnectionManager();
    }
   return instance;
}



public void send(String str){

    try{
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(access_point.getOutputStream())),true);
        out.println(str);
    }

    catch(IOException e){       
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

AND HERE IS HOW I CALLED IT ON ONE OF THE ACTIVITIES

```
private static ConnectionManager command = ConnectionManager.getInstance();
.........
command.send("Turn on");
```

Comment: From your question its not clear where you are stuck. But if you are going for Singleton design pattern, you can go for 'enum' based singleton. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java

Comment: @VishaID I am making a simple app that sends strings over WiFi. Since I have several activities, once I go back to the main UI the connection is lost. From some research that I did it is highly recommended to use a singleton class that handles the socket and that can be accessed by all my activities. I hope this is more clear. Please excuse any mistakes or misconceptions, since I am very new to these concepts.

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582972/android-auth-keep-http-connection-use-connection-in-few-activity

Comment: @MarcVanDaele Yes, it is similar, but instead I just connect to a server and send data to it. The link is quite useful, thank you !

Comment: I tried the method that @MarcVanDaele suggested but did not manage anything. My app crashes now. I posted my code in the question above and would highly appreciate if someone had a look at it.

Comment: where does your app crashes? please add logcat output.